# C# implement an ICollection interface for a list of wrapped data

Tags: c#, collections, interface, delegates

I could use some input on how to properly implement an interface for some wrapped data.

I have a class which contains a List<T_wrapper>. T_wrapper is a class which contains member variables of type T_key and T_value, along with other data.

The implementation is similar to a dictionary (always sorted by T_key with max 1 entry per key), but for the sake of argument assume I cannot use a dictionary, and List<T_wrapper> is what I am forced to use. I am stuck with a List of a wrapper class and following interface.

I need to implement an interface for the class which returns an ICollection<T_key> without creating an entirely new List.
Here is the real question: *Is there a way to essentially "forward" the member keys in the wrapped class, such as using a delegate, instead of creating an entirely new List?*

Here is a bare-bones example of what I need:

```
public class MyCollection<T_key, T_value> : ICollection_requiring_interface
    where T_key : System.Enum
{
    public List<T_wrapper> DataList=
       new List<T_wrapper>();

    public class T_wrapper
    {
        public T_key Key;
        public T_value Value;
    }

    public ICollection<T_key> GetKeyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return DataList. ???? => some way to forward T_wrapper.Key
        }
    }
}
```

I am still new to C#, coming from a C++ background, and am still hazy with interfaces, delegates and iterators. I have scoured online and found several ways that are similar, but don't work.

**Respectfully please don't offer alternatives, as I am currently stuck with this.** However, I am all ears for a come-to-earth that what I am asking is not possible/has a fundamental misunderstanding of the language.

Constructive feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: "Respectfully please don't offer alternatives" <--- you seem to have misunderstood what Stack Overflow is about. Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk. Answers should not only help you, but also future visitors, who are not "stuck with this".

Comment: If you expose an `ICollection<TKey>` that means you are exposing something that allows you to *add* a key. Just a key. How can you possibly add a key without also adding a value? I don't think you can, exposing it as an `ICollection<TKey>` is probably inappropriate. Have you considered exposing an `IEnumerable<TKey>` instead?

Comment: `IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>` can also be an option. @JohnWu

Comment: What does ""forward" the member keys in the wrapped class" mean?

Comment: What you are asking is not possible and is a fundamental misunderstanding of the language.

Comment: Can you explain why "`List<T_wrapper>` is what I am forced to use"?

Comment: I'm just here for the comments. \*Gets some popcorn\*

Comment: @TheGeneral - Oh man, me too. This is an awesome question. It's like, "I need a boat, but the boat has to be able to go underwater. I know someone will suggest a submarine, but I am stuck and can't use a submarine. Oh, and it can't get wet either."

Answer (score -1):

### Main answer:

I realize what you want. If you have additional information in your **Wrapper class** than you could implement the way below:

```
        public interface IMyCollection<TKey>
        {
            ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection();
            //add some here or in class methods to edit the values or add them with key
        }

        public class Wrapper<TKey, TValue> where TKey : Enum
        {
            public TKey Key;
            public TValue Value;

            public Wrapper(TKey key)
            {
                Key = key;
                //and other things you need
            }
            
            public Wrapper(TKey key, TValue value)
            {
                Key = key;
                Value = value;
                //and other things you need
            }
        }
        
        public class MyCollection<TKey, TValue> : IMyCollection<TKey> where TKey : Enum
        {
            private ICollection<TKey> _keys = new List<TKey>();
            private ICollection<Wrapper<TKey, TValue>> _dataList = new List<Wrapper<TKey, TValue>>();

            public ICollection<Wrapper<TKey, TValue>> DataList
            {
                get
                {
                    var list = _dataList;
                    foreach (var key in _keys)
                    {
                        if (!list.Any(w => w.Key.Equals(key)))
                        {
                            _dataList.Add(new Wrapper<TKey, TValue>(key));
                        }
                    }

                    return list;
                }
            }

            public ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection()
            {
                return _keys;
            }
        }
```

#### Deprecated answer below line:

---

You dont need to implement your own wrapper. Use IDictionary instead, or if you need more functionality than implement it in your wrapper class. And please follow naming conventions for [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) and [interfaces](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/).

Here is what you need:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace YourProjecy
{
    public interface IMyCollection<TKey>
    {
        ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection();
    }

    public class MyCollection<TKey, TValue> : IMyCollection<TKey> where TKey : System.Enum
    {
        public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> DataList = new();

        public ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection()
        {
            return DataList.Select(dl => dl.Key).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to have reference on keys collection to edit than you can implemet code below:

```cs
        public interface IMyCollection<TKey>
        {
            ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection();
            //add some here or in class methods to edit the values or add them with key
        }

        public class MyCollection<TKey, TValue> : IMyCollection<TKey> where TKey : System.Enum
        {
            private ICollection<TKey>  _keys = new List<TKey>();
            private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dataList = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

            public IDictionary<TKey, TValue> DataList
            {
                get
                {
                    var dictionary = _dataList;
                    foreach (var key in _keys)
                    {
                        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            _dataList.Add(key, default);
                        }
                    }
                    return dictionary;
                }
            }
            public ICollection<TKey> GetKeyCollection()
            {
                return _keys;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The expectation is that you can add new elements with `ICollection<TKey>`, but you're copying the original collection with `.ToList()`, so it makes this approach kind of useless.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's kind of wrong to have a reference to collection that is a part of more complicated collection but I added a code to have reference on keys collection with possibility of editing the whole key-value collection

Comment: I see what TO need. Added solution corresponding to main question